# Install failure for LTS 16.04 nouveau MEM_FAULT

Tags: nvidia, nouveau

I'm trying to install 16.04 on a machine with Windows 10. I got the iso and created boot disk. It starts to load but then I see the following screen

[image]

I did some searching here and sounds like maybe failure to load the installer. The suggestion there for Ctrl+Alt+F1 does not do anything for me.

["[drm] nouveau 0000:04:0.0: PFIFO_DMA_PUSHER" in the kernel.log file and the boot freezes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87361/drm-nouveau-0000040-0-pfifo-dma-pusher-in-the-kernel-log-file-and-the-boo)

Windows is running fine. The graphic card is a Nvidia GeForce 9500 GT.
AMD 64 Dual core 4800.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Try booting the Ubuntu Live DVD with the `nomodeset` parameter set. If that works, the problem is related to your video card, and will probably be solved by installing the correct video driver after install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot the Ubuntu Live DVD with the `nomodeset` parameter set. If that works, the problem is related to your video card, and will can be solved by installing the correct video driver after install.

Once booted, open the `Software & Updates` app, select the `Additional Drivers` tab, and click the radio button to install the Nvidia driver. Reboot and you should be fine.

Comment: so I did the Software update and now I am unable to start Ubuntu :( I get some tocblock error. Any idea how I can undo the nvidia update? I am able to goto recovery mode.

Comment: so I was able to get the apt install history log and then do a apt-get remove. Atleast booting up now even though some errors still show.

Comment: So you've had to uninstall the Nvidia driver? What kinds of errors are you seeing now? I'm not any kind of expert with Nvidia cards, but I do believe that there are 2 or 3 choices for the driver... one is called BumbleBee, then they have some kind of Pro version, etc... you'll have to research this a little yourself. I'd search AskUbuntu for "Nvidia GeForce 9500 GT" and see what you find.