# How to specify the monitor driver in the installer

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, system-installation, vga

I had to reinstall kubuntu on my PC due to hard-disk problems. The 16.04.4 installer boots up ok, then on the desktop it has the install icon, once I click it, it freezes. Have reproduced this reliably. So went back to the old 14.04.1 installer, installed kubuntu, all went ok. Then I upgraded to 16.04, upgrade went ok, after booting nto the new OS the freeze came back. I have noticed that in the tray area, around the clock whenever something would pop up a window, the whole PC froze. Mouse would move but nothing else works (ctrl+F1 neither). Once I have seen some strange pixels so I have installed the proprietary nvidia driver (nvidia-current) and now it is working well. (If someone interested, I have this card: NVIDIA Corporation GK106 [GeForce GTX 660])

My question: can I rerun the installer and specify a driver that is not the one that is used by default for this card? My guess is that the nouveau driver is used and that it has a bug. From vague memory I think there is a framebuffer driver which might be good enough to get me through an installer. Can I specify somehow to use the fb driver for the installer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Must have been sleepy yesterday, this question is already answered.

[Install failure for LTS 16.04 nouveau MEM_FAULT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962939/install-failure-for-lts-16-04-nouveau-mem-fault)

Haven't tried it but my guess is that this will fix the problem:
"Boot the Ubuntu Live DVD with the nomodeset parameter set"

Hopefully it will work:

"Many open source drivers have removed support for non-kernel mode setting, so in those cases when you use nomodeset you will end up falling back to the very basic VESA un-accelerated driver. This is very much a performance and feature hit."

https://askubuntu.com/a/249579/806038

Will try it and if it does not I'll report back.

(I wish we still had the alternate installer that did the job reliably...)